# Search Application {id} is not ready

Tags: 2013, search, central-administration, searchserviceapplication

I'm using SharePoint 2013 and currently troubleshooting why content isn't getting indexed.

When viewing Central Admin > Services on Server, SharePoint Server Search status is "Started" but when viewing the Search Service Application page, the system status is showing

> Search Application {id} is not ready

If I then select any of the diagnostic or crawling options, I get the below error.

[image: Error when assessing search settings in Central Admin]

In the event viewer on one of the servers, I am frequently getting the below  error. I'm not certain this is related but it is referring to the Search Service

> A failure was reported when trying to invoke a service application:
>   EndpointFailure Process Name: OWSTIMER Process ID: 14436 AppDomain
>   Name: DefaultDomain AppDomain ID: 1 Service Application Uri:
>   urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:service:2096584e626d4cfdb9dee97fd5909266#authority=urn:uuid:a4deafa459bf413aaf3ebb29bef2e529&authority=https://ns-vnc-swfe-001:32844/Topology/topology.svc
>   Active Endpoints: 1 Failed Endpoints:1

Can anyone please advise where I can go next to trouble shoot? Any help would be very much appreciated.